# Is there a performance penalty for binding multiple event handlers to the scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-events

Is there a **significant** **performance** difference between binding multiple `$(window).on('scroll', fn)`s vs combing all of the logic into *one* event handler?

My code is better organized with just one event handler but I'd like to get the fastest performance out of this particular module. In this use-case there might be 10~100 handlers attached to the scroll event.

Comment: I think the only way you're likely to get a definitive answer here is to benchmark both approaches and probably across the target browsers too

Comment: What is the code flow going to look like? Only one of the 10-100 handlers will end up firing based on some condition or if you operate with the single handler, you'll end up firing all of the things that would have been fired in the individual handlers programmatically?

Comment: you need to debounce scroll because it can fire dozens or hundreds of times  a second. i would fire a custom event from my debounced scroll event, and have the many subscribers listen for that new custom event.

Comment: Each instance is handling it's own debouncing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified AlliterativeAlice's code after considering Bergi's comment. Using the native scroll event in *Chrome* **I didn't see any significant difference in speed between the two approaches**. Run the code below by copy and pasting into the JavaScript console of this web page, what results to you get?...

```
function log() {
  console.log(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '))
}

var count100 = 0;
var count1 = 0;

function test100() {
  $(window).off('scroll');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      count100++;
    });
  }
  var startTime = performance.now();

  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    window.scroll(0, 0);

    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      window.scroll(0, j + 1);
    }
  }

  var endTime = performance.now();
  log("100 handlers: ", endTime - startTime);
}


function test1() {
  var count = 0;
  $(window).off('scroll');
  var fns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    fns.push(function() {
      count1++;
    });
  }

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    fns.forEach(function(f) {
      f();
    })
  });

  var startTime = performance.now();

  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    window.scroll(0, 0);

    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      window.scroll(0, j + 1);
    }
  }

  var endTime = performance.now();
  log("1 handler: ", endTime - startTime);
}

var testCount = 0;
var numberOfRuns = 20;

function logCount() {
  console.log("-->count1: ", count1);
  console.log("-->count100: ", count100);
}

function runTestA() {
  test1();
  if (++testCount<numberOfRuns) setTimeout(runTestB, 10);
  else setTimeout(logCount, 10);
}

function runTestB() {
  test100();
  if (++testCount<numberOfRuns) setTimeout(runTestA, 10);
  else setTimeout(logCount, 10);
}

runTestA();
```

Comment: I tried running this and the handlers don't seem to be executing at all for some reason (tested by logging the value of `count` along with the result time at the end of each test.) I thought this may be due to `$(window).off('scroll');` apparently being called after the scroll handlers are bound in each test, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AlliterativeAlice, I can't get it to work at all using the inline code editor, but it works now if you paste into the console.